# Add row number to this T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add ROW numbers to this query result?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById,
  COUNT(VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById) AS NumCars,
  aspnet_Users.UserName
FROM
  VehicleSpecs
  INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById = aspnet_Users.UserId
WHERE
  (LEN(VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById) > 0)
GROUP BY
  VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById,
  aspnet_Users.UserName
ORDER BY
  NumCars DESC
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NumCars)`

EDIT:

```
WITH    t1 AS 
( SELECT DISTINCT
            VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById ,
            COUNT(VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById) AS NumCars ,
            aspnet_Users.UserName
   FROM     VehicleSpecs
            INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById = aspnet_Users.UserId
   WHERE    ( LEN(VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById) > 0 )
   GROUP BY VehicleSpecs.SubmittedById ,
            aspnet_Users.UserName
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NumCars ), *
FROM    t1
ORDER BY NumCars
```

Comment: Tomek I don't understand where in the query I have to put that?

Comment: I have tried your query but I get this error:
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'VehicleSpecs'.

I also have tried with [CarSpecs].[dbo].[VehicleSpecs] ...but I get the same error...

Comment: Very strange the error appears only in MSSQL studio and in my asp.net application works.

Comment: I need to order by NumCars DESC and if I add DESC then the row numbers are displayed in reverse orders, they should be displayed 1,2,3 ...

Comment: I have solved the problem, Thanks ! I had to add DESC to both ORDER BY

Comment: @MarioM: have you selected correct database in the SSMS before running the query? You can also put this statement before the query: USE yourDbName;

Answer (score 20):

Wrap you entire query in a sub query and add `row_number` in the outer query.

```
select *, row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as rn
from
  (
    select distinct -- your columns
    from YourTable
  ) as T
order by NumCars desc
```

Comment: Does MS SQL not allow an empty `over()` clause?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Not for row_number. It does for max and min.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: thanks. Wouldn't `order by 0` just do the same thing?

Comment: @MartinSmith -  Yes I thought that could be important at first but since he is doing a group by as well I don't think it would matter in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It interprets any integer constant as an attempt to use a column ordinal and that is disallowed. constants aren't permitted in general though either. `ORDER BY 1.0/0` works though as this is not integer datatype and doesn't get folded into a constant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - That would make sense but it gives an error "Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions."

Comment: Mikael I have tried as you said, but I get this error: 
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @MarioM Ah, yes you need to move your order by statement to the outer query. `ORDER BY NumCars`