# How to add sequence number column into result data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add row number to this T-SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150378/add-row-number-to-this-t-sql-query)

Im using sql server 2008.

When I type: select * from Employee. The result like this:

```
EmpID    |    EmpName    |    Salary
-------------------------------------
DB1608   |    David      |    100000
JT2607   |    John       |    150000
AM1707   |    Ann        |    140000
ML1211   |    Mary       |    125000
```

But I want the result like this:

```
No      |    EmpID    |    EmpName    |    Salary
--------------------------------------------------
1       |    DB1608   |    David      |    100000
2       |    JT2607   |    John       |    150000
3       |    AM1707   |    Ann        |    140000
4       |    ML1211   |    Mary       |    125000
```

The column "No" is the auto increment number, and NOT the identity field in this table.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) - however you will want to find a reliable and predictable column or expression to order by, otherwise the row numbers will be applied in an arbitrary way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx))

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID ASC) AS No, 
    EmpID, EmpName, Salary
FROM Employee
```

### [See in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09bf0/1)

Comment: This is what I was referring to in my comment - without confirmation that it doesn't matter, your ROW_NUMBER() will be applied in a different order than the desired output listed in the question.