# How to serialize a column number in a datatable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable, datagridview

In the column "TOTAL" is the result of calculations in sql so that the column is an alias and the column has descending in Sql. So how can I set the rank column datatable can create serial number sequence from number one onwards?

```vb
Public Sub filltable2(ByVal dtgrd As Object, ByVal design As String)
    Dim publictable As New DataTable

    Try
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        publictable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Rank", GetType(Integer)))
        Dim count As Integer = 1
 da.Fill(publictable)
        dtgrd.DataSource = publictable

        Select Case design
            Case "trial"

        End Select

        da.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Table 1

| EMPID | NAME | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | JACK | 389.11 |
| 10046 | JOHN | 372.62 |

Desired Result table 1

| EMPID | NAME | TOTAL | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | JACK | 389.11 | 1 |
| 10046 | JOHN | 372.62 | 2 |

Comment: If `cmd` contains an SQL query, then you could do it there, e.g., see [How to add sequence number column into result data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597041/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton , My database uses ms access can use your solution?

Comment: Not sure if you're maybe trying to over complicate this? You're already returning an ordered data table from your db based on Total, you're already adding a column to it for the Rank.  Why not just iterate the publictable rows and populate the rank?  Although I would suggest as rank id based on the record order of Total, having a specific field for Rank is probably in some ways asking for trouble

Comment: @Hursey , `Why not just iterate the publictable rows and populate the rank? ` What you mean like how I can implement as per your recommendation

Comment: Using a `For Each` loop you can iterate over the publictable.Rows collection and update the field values directly via row.Item("Rank").  Plenty of examples around for that