# row_number() over() combined with order by

Tags: sql, db2

How can I add a sequential row number to a query that is using order by?

Let say I have a request in this form :

```
SELECT row_number() over(), data
FROM myTable
ORDER BY data
```

This will produce the desired result as rows are ordered by "data", but the row numbers are also ordered by data. I understand this is normal as my row number is generated before the order by, but how can I generate this row number after the order by?

I did try to use a subquery like this :

```
SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY data), *
FROM
(  
   SELECT data 
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY data
) As t1
```

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150378/add-row-number-to-this-t-sql-query), but DB2 doesn't seem to support this syntax `SELECT ..., * FROM`

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use alaias name before '*'

```
SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY data), t1.*
FROM
(  
   SELECT data 
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY data
) As t1
```

You don't need a subquery to do this,

```
   SELECT data , row_number() over(ORDER BY data) as rn
   FROM myTable
   ORDER BY data
```

Comment: It works with the t1.*. I oversimplified my example too much : I use a rand() to generate a column in the query on wich I do my order by. placing this column in the over() function did not work in a single query. Anyway your answer get me going so thanks a lot !